# Tomcat 7 startup failing with Java SE 1.7 in Solaris

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, solaris, java-7

I am facing a strange issue where the tomcat version 7.0.57 is not starting up with JDK version 1.7. If I simply change the JAVA_HOME to any of my JDK 1.6 installation, tomcat starts up smoothly as expected. The OS is Sun Solaris and the JDK 1.7 installer I have used is 'jdk-7u60-ea-bin-b15-solaris-sparc-17_apr_2014.tar.gz'. I have given below the stack trace from the tomcat startup logs:

```
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               SunOS
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            5.10
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          sparc
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_51-b13
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/logging.properties
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.library.path=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/endorsed
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/temp
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8086]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8086]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fd1
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.initProto(Native Method)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.<clinit>(PlainSocketImpl.java:39)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.setImpl(ServerSocket.java:289)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:230)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:398)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8056"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8056]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8056]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.SocksSocketImpl
  at java.net.ServerSocket.setImpl(ServerSocket.java:289)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:230)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:398)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2250 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/html5-web.war
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:43 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/html5-web/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[/html5-web]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: address
  at java.net.InetAddress.init(Native Method)
  at java.net.InetAddress.<clinit>(InetAddress.java:271)
  at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(SeedGenerator.java:176)
  at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(SeedGenerator.java:162)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy(SeedGenerator.java:161)
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:184)
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:203)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:477)
  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/html5-web] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/html5-web.war has finished in 8,500 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:203)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:477)
  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT has finished in 416 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/docs
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[/docs]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:203)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:477)
  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/docs] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/docs has finished in 106 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/examples
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[/examples]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:203)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:477)
  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/examples] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/examples has finished in 812 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/host-manager
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[/host-manager]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:203)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:477)
  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/host-manager] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/host-manager has finished in 167 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/manager
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error manager.start()
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[/manager]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder
  at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:203)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
  at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:477)
  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:239)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 12 more


Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/manager] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /application/paragnq2a/parsit4/users/jyotir/staging/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/manager has finished in 293 ms
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10592 ms
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.InetAddress
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8056"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8056"]
Nov 18, 2014 10:45:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8056"]
```

I did lot of google on this and found that similar issues were faced in macOS but not in Solaris. The resolution for macOS was released on jdk 1.7u60. In my case I have tried jdk1.7u51 and jdk1.7u60 both but the issue remains same. Please can anybody help?

Comment: What platform? 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

1. Why are you installing an EA release of an old version of Java ?  (EA = Early Access release).
2. Are you going for Java 32-bit or Java 64-bit? . If going for the latter (you should!) remember that in Java 7 this is distributed by Oracle as *two* install packages. First you'll need to install the 32-bit package and then install the 64-bit package on top of that. Install is simple: Just unpack both to same location. From Java 8 onwards this is no longer needed as Oracle no longer distributes the 32-bit version, so now there's only one package.
3. Why are you installing JDK, not JRE?  (you only need JRE, see Tomcat's `RUNNING.txt` file). Installing the JDK doesn't hurt, you just don't need it. The most appropriate package to install, IMHO, is the one Oracle calls "Server JRE".
4. What is the outcome of running `<path to your Java install>/bin/java -version` ?
5. What is your Solaris OS version?

The mistake people most often make is #2 above.

Comment: I believe you that the java 7 distribution is two packages for Solaris, but for Linux you only need the 64-bit package if you want 64-bit.

Comment: @DanPritts. True, but the question is specifically about Solaris.

Comment: understood - just wanted to point it out to other folks who, like me, got here anyway via a generic tomcat search.