# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder

Tags: java, security, random

Getting below error randomly in the Prod environment for an application. However with the next run the error was not reported and it got successfully started.

Error:-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.integration.MessageHeaders.<init>(MessageHeaders.java:96) ~[spring-integration-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage.<init>(GenericMessage.java:68) ~[spring-integration-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage.<init>(GenericMessage.java:49) ~[spring-integration-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.message.ErrorMessage.<init>(ErrorMessage.java:33) ~[spring-integration-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:83) ~[spring-integration-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Could anyone please share some suggestion on above error, how can we resolve??
What could be the cause of sudden classDefNotFound??
Nothing was changed in the application. So far have received only once.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244093/eclipse-will-not-start-error-13

Comment: Hello Alberto, Thanks for the suggestion, but not helpful.

Comment: Could someone let me know if we should handle it be using try and catch and some do some action in the catch block. As NoClassDefFounderro is a type of error not exception. If someone has any insight on this please share?

Comment: another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996636/tomcat-7-startup-failing-with-java-se-1-7-in-solaris